# Dependency injection and unit test

Tags: unit-testing, dependency-injection

It is wonderful when a domain class that I want to test depends upon stateless objects, I can use dependency inject to do all the tricks so that I can test the function that I would like on the class. But what if the objects upon which the domain class depends are stateful? Can I still employ the dependency inject technique in this case? What I mean by "stateful object" is an object whose state is initialized through a constructor. Can you still use DI container to do the initialization?

Comment: Why should you not be able to use DI on stateful application. The only difference is that a stateless app always returns the same value when calling a method and a stateful app is dependent on the state it is in. But that is all testable. DI makes it even easier to test.

Comment: what I meant stateful object is object's state is initialized through constructor. when use DI configurations, it is hard to put the object state in the DI configuration file

Comment: If you use interfaces you should be able to inject them inside your contructor call. And whyle testing you create a dummy implementation for the interface using stubs/mocks. What language or DI framework are you using?

Comment: sorry, what I really want to ask is not just unit test, in an application, when using dependency injection, it is easy to inject stateless dependent object, how does it work, when the dependent object happen to be an stateful object, with state initialized through construcotr?

Comment: Show us a code example, so that we know precisely what you're talking about.

Comment: Generally speaking, personally I don't see an issue injecting stateless and having to deal with Unit Testing. You just need to stub out the statefull object. And test only what's inside the function. This is also valid for stateless objects. It is hard to give you a specific answer without a code sample.